# Pricing Equity Swaptions

Tags: option-pricing, equities, pricing

Consider a swaption to enter into a standard equity swap as a fixed-rate payer, equity receiver, in which the notional principal is fixed.

If the strike is K. the underlying swap starts at time 0=n and terminates at m.

Then the swap will have a value at the expiration of

$$SW(0,m)=Max(0,R-K) \sum_{i=1}^{m}B(0,i)$$

where $B(0, i)$ stand for zero-coupon bond with 1\$ face value that matures at $i$. And $R=\frac{1-B(0, m)}{\sum_{i=1}^{m}B(0,i) }$.

My question is how to derive this equation?
(Since R is the swap rate, is it possible that swap rate can replace equity return?)
Please give me some hints regarding this question.
[image]
This result was from “The Pricing of Equity Swaps and Swaptions.” The
Journal of Derivatives, 5 (Summer, 1998), page 29.